# How to use two filters in one datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, filter

I have one datagrid that I am using to alternate between showing two different data sources. I have a filter working for one of the data sources, but it dosent work for the other one. Basically, one data grid showing the first data source, then I can click a button to switch to the other data source in the same grid but I cannot filter this one.

Here is the code I have for the filter on the first data source that works:

```
private Dictionary<string, PortStatus> _dicPortStatus = new Dictionary<string, PortStatus>();

        private void cmbGroups_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Combo box selection changed.  Re-bind data
            string selectedGroup = (string)cmbGroups.SelectedItem;

            //Re-bind the grid
            dgPortStatus.DataContext = _dicPortStatus[selectedGroup].Portstatus.DefaultView;

        }

        private void txtFilterIn_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FilterDataGrid(txtFilterIn.Text, txtFilterOut.Text, _dicPortStatus[cmbGroups.SelectedItem.ToString()]);
        }

        private void btnFilterInClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtFilterIn.Clear();
        }

        private void txtFilterOut_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            FilterDataGrid(txtFilterIn.Text, txtFilterOut.Text, _dicPortStatus[cmbGroups.SelectedItem.ToString()]);
            //((CollectionView)dgPortStatus.ItemsSource).Refresh();

        }

        private void btnFilterOutClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtFilterOut.Clear();
        }

        private void FilterDataGrid(string inText, string outText, DataSet ds)
        {
            if (ds != null )
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(outText))
                {
                    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sbFilter = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            if (dc.DataType == typeof(string))
                            {
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText))
                                {
                                    if (sbFilter.Length > 0)
                                        sbFilter.Append(" OR ");
                                    sbFilter.Append("(");
                                    sbFilter.Append(dc.ColumnName + " LIKE '%" + inText + "%'");

                                }

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outText))
                                {
                                    if (sbFilter.Length > 0)
                                        sbFilter.Append(" AND ");
                                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText))
                                        sbFilter.Append("(");
                                    sbFilter.Append(dc.ColumnName + " NOT LIKE '%" + outText + "%'");
                                }
                                sbFilter.Append(")");
                            }

                            if (dc.DataType == typeof(Int32) || dc.DataType == typeof(Double))
                            {                

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText))
                                {
                                    if (sbFilter.Length > 0)
                                        sbFilter.Append(" OR ");
                                    sbFilter.Append("(");
                                    sbFilter.Append("CONVERT(" + dc.ColumnName + ", System.String)" + " LIKE '%" + inText + "%'");

                                }

                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(outText))
                                {
                                    if (sbFilter.Length > 0)
                                        sbFilter.Append(" AND ");
                                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inText))
                                        sbFilter.Append("(");
                                    sbFilter.Append("CONVERT(" + dc.ColumnName + ", System.String)" + " NOT LIKE '%" + outText + "%'");
                                }
                                sbFilter.Append(")");
                            }
                        }

                        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = sbFilter.ToString();
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                    {
                        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Empty; 
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So if it isn't doing what you think it should, what -is- it doing?

Are you getting back a blank datagrid, is it not filtering, what is happening?

Also, have you tried stepping through the code and checking variable values at different stages to see if the problem lies within your back-end code or if it is in how you are interfaced with DataGrid?

Comment: When i type in the filter textbox when I am viewing the first data source in the grid, it filters fine. When I click on the button to view the second data source, and it populates the grid...then I cannot filter the grid. I type in the type box and nothing happens.

Comment: @Joe Just to confirm, have you stepped through the FilterDataGrid while debugging to see if it is searching the correct table and returning the right true/false for each row?

Comment: I am in the process of stepping through it now. Debugging is something I am still learning. But this method looks to be what is causing the problem.

Comment: If you haven't dealt with it much before, while debugging, if you step to the line immediately after an execution of code, you can mouse-over the variable and it will show you the data enclosed in that variable.

Comment: when i mouse over the variables, what i enter into the textbox shows up, but the datagrid dosent update with what is in the text box.

Comment: Okay, as you step through the solution, get to where it has completed sbFilter and confirm that it is filtering correctly and showing the correct SQL command that you need for it to properly filter.

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is in this function

```
dgPortStatus.DataContext = _dicPortStatus[selectedGroup].Portstatus.DefaultView;
```

in this function you are setting datacontext , i think you should set DataSource instead.

```
dgPortStatus.DataSource = _dicPortStatus[selectedGroup].Portstatus.DefaultView;
```